# Initialize static array for use it in other static variable of other class

Tags: php, arrays, function, variables, static

```
class Assignation {
  private $VVal_1 = 1;
  private $VNam_1 = "One";
  //....Multiple Items
  private $VVal_2000 = 2000; //For Example
  private $VNam_2000 = "Two Thousands"; //For Example
  private static $Hash = array(); //How to initialize???

  private static function Assigning(){
  //This function for to assign the array elements (initialize)
    global $Hash;
    $this->Hash = array(); //to empty Hash variable and not add more data than it should.
    $this->Hash[$this->VVal_1] = $this->VNam_1;
    //....Multiple Items
    $this->Hash[$this->VVal_2000] = $this->VNam_2000;
  }

  public static function GetVal($Nam) {
    $this->Assigning();  //or use self::Assigning(); //I want to avoid this call
    if (array_search($Nam, $this->Hash))
      return array_search($Nam, $this->Hash);
    return -1;//error
  }

  public static function GetNam($Val) {
    $this->Assigning();  //or use self::Assigning(); //I want to avoid this call
    if (array_key_exists($Val, $this->Hash))
      return $this->Hash[$Val];
    return "Error";
  }
}

Class Testing {
  static $OtherVal = Assignation::GetVal("BLABLA"); //for example
  static $OtherNam = Assignation::GetNam(20); //for example
  //Other functions...
}
```

Hi, you can see my script or code php... 
I need to initialize the **Hash** array, this have **static** word because I need to use it in other static function. And this "other function" need to use it for other static variable...
I need to know how to implement it the right way..

Thanks chep.-.

---

```
<?php
echo "pre-Class Assignation<br/>";
class Assignation {
  private $VVal_1 = 1;
  private $VNam_1 = "One";
  private $VVal_2K = 2000;
  private $VNam_2K = "Two Thousands";
  private static $Hash = array();

  private static function Assigning(){
    if(!empty(self::$Hash)) return;
    self::$Hash[$this->VVal_1] = $this->VNam_1;
    self::$Hash[$this->VVal_2K] = $this->VNam_2K;
  }

  public static function GetVal($Nam) {
    self::Assigning();
    if (array_search($Nam, self::$Hash)) return array_search($Nam, self::$Hash);
    return -1;//error
  }

  public static function GetNam($Val) {
    self::Assigning();
    if (array_key_exists($Val, self::$Hash)) return self::$Hash[$Val];
    return "Error";
  }
}
echo "post-Class Testing<br/>";
echo Assignation::GetVal("BLABLA");
echo "post-Class Mid<br/>";
echo Assignation::GetNam(20);
echo "post-Class Sample<br/>";
//Testing::MyPrint();
?>
```

This code is not running, somebody help me testing the code...
result:

```
pre-Class Assignation
post-Class Assignation
post-Class Testing
```

that mean:
"    echo Assignation::GetVal("BLABLA");"
have error...

Answer (score 1):

In `Assigning()`, try using `self::$Hash` rather than `$this->Hash` and remove the `global $Hash`. Same applies for calling `Assigning()`: `self::Assigning()` as your comments suggest.

`$this` references the current object, so you must use `self::` for all static functions and member data when inside the class.

Also, if this is your real code and not just a sample, you may want to check whether you have already done initialization, otherwise you will be doing it for every call to `GetVal()` and `GetNam()`. You could do this by adding something like `if(!empty(self::$Hash)) return` at the beginning of `Assigning()`

**EDIT**

```
private static function Assigning() {
    if(!empty(self::$Hash)) return; // already populated
    self::$Hash = array();
    self::$Hash[$this->VVal_1] = $this->VNam_1;
    //....Multiple Items
    self::$Hash[$this->VVal_2K] = $this->VNam_2K;
}
```

Comment: I updated my answer to give an example of what you need to do